# tableview in viewcontroller expand width to ipad (or larger screen device)

Tags: ios, tableview, viewcontroller

I have a tableview within a viewcontroller.  For iphone6 simulator it looks good but when I view it on a iPad Air or larger screen device the tableview does not expand in width.  The following is how it looks:

[image: tableview on ipad]

Is there a dynamic way I can configure the tableview to expand the width?

Comment: you have not set proper constraint for table view .

Comment: I have added constraints on the tableview to right: 0, bottom: 0 but it didn't work.  The tableview also has a width property which is set for iphone6 simulator.  I think that is what's causing the width to be set even for a Ipad display.

Comment: Yeah, the width constraint is definitely your problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set it programmatically so that it loads during initial call and in viewWillAppear:

```
 let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
 let screenWidth = screenSize.width
 let screenHeight = screenSize.height
 tableView.frame.size.width = screenWidth
 tableView.frame.size.height = screenHeight
```